# Python Dataframe how to sum row values with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to group a column 'Over_Id' in Dataframe and also sum values of column `runs_scored` while grouping.

If I use `groupby`, I loose my other columns

Eg:

```
ball.groupby(['Match_Id','Innings_Id','Over_Id'])['runs_scored'].sum()
```

[image]

I was able to get my `runs_scored` column, but in a new Dataframe, not my actual as seen in the image. I can't `merge`, because my addition of `runs_scored` column is based on 3 columns.

In short, I want only 1 entry for each `Over_Id` and it's corresponding `runs_scored`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just group by every column besides the `runs_scored` column, and then find the sum.

```
c = df.columns.difference(['runs_scored']).tolist()
df = df.groupby(c, as_index=False).runs_scored.sum()
```

On a side note, it seems you have a lot of redundant data entries. Have you looked at normalising your tables?

Comment: Worked! thanks. I'm using this data for training my model, also there are other fields which have different data (haven't displayed all in the image)

Comment: @JaskaranSinghPuri Alright then, you're good. The upside of a single table is that there's no need for merges and joins, which are expensive usually :-)